# Using a Boost basic deadline timer to call a class method

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'd like to bind a timer to a callback method in my class.
Could you please help me correcting my code ?

```
tftp_connection::tftp_connection (std::string id,
                                  std::string file_name,
                                  connection_type_enum connection_type,
                                  tftp_server* server,
                                  boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
                : timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)) {
    ...
    //timer.async_wait(callback);
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::callback ), this);

    ...
} 
... 

void tftp_connection::callback(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/)
{
    // TIME OUT
}
```

The error is:

```
Compilation error:
/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:22: Type 'void (tftp_connection::*)(const boost::system::error_code &)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::callback ), this);
```

should be

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::callback, this));
```

You need to bind the object to the member function, since the member function cannot work without the object it belongs to.

See [boost examples for using member functions as callbacks with async_wait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem ! I had to change the method signature too (callback without parameters), and now it compiles.